# How to create a loadding spinner (javascript-ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i create this loading spinner? saw this on the following [URL](https://jqueryhouse.com/jquery-ajax-loading-effect-a-simple-way-to-display-content-using-ajax-request/)

i wrote the following code below, but i am not sure how to add code in success fucntion, they have time out function but its looks different that my code.

```
                               $('#content').html('<img id="loader-img" alt="" src="http://adrian-design.com/images/loading.gif" width="100" height="100" align="center" />');
                               $.ajax({
                                   type: "POST",
                                   url: "Checkout_Payment.aspx/ChargeCreditCard",
                                   data: '{NameVB: "' + NameJS + '"}',
                                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                   dataType: "json",
                                   success: OnSuccess,
                                   failure: OnFailure,
                                   error: OnError
                               });
                               function OnSuccess(response) {
                                   var getResponse = response.d;
                                   if (getResponse.indexOf('success') >= 0) {
                                       var order_ID_Array = getResponse.split("_");
                                       var order_ID = order_ID_Array[1];
                                       window.location.href = "Checkout_Receipt.aspx?OID=" + order_ID ;
                                   }
                               }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there you just have to `hide` the image after the `success` of your ajax

```
$('#content').html('<img id="loader-img" alt="" src="http://adrian-design.com/images/loading.gif" width="100" height="100" align="center" />');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Checkout_Payment.aspx/ChargeCreditCard",
data: '{NameVB: "' + NameJS + '"}',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: OnSuccess,
failure: OnFailure,
error: OnError
});
function OnSuccess(response) {
  $("#loader-img").hide(); //REMOVES THE LOADING UPON RECEIVING RESPONSE
   var getResponse = response.d;
   if (getResponse.indexOf('success') >= 0) {
     var order_ID_Array = getResponse.split("_");
     var order_ID = order_ID_Array[1];
     window.location.href = "Checkout_Receipt.aspx?OID=" + order_ID ;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! my first loading spinner!